# Cancellation token does not propagate to controller's action while uploading multipart/form file (ASP.NET Core 7)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, cancellation-token, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core console application, hosted on the user's PC as a Windows service, which communicates with a remote server for executing some tasks, like uploading a file as a stream from the local machine to the server.

The remote server has the following controller's action for receiving files as a stream:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipartFormData]
[DisableFormValueModelBinding]
[RequestSizeLimit(524_288_000)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (Request.ContentType is null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid content type");
    }

    var fileUploadResultCode = await 
        _fileService.UploadFileAsync(HttpContext.Request.Body,
        Request.ContentType, cancellationToken);

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Upload), fileUploadResultCode);
}
```

This is the method on the client which makes the POST request for uploading a file:

```
public async Task<int> Upload(string file)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    
    await using FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(file);
    
    using MultipartFormDataContent content = new()
    {
        { new StringContent("string1"), "string1" },
        { new StringContent("string2"), "string2" },
        { new StreamContent(fileStream), "file", fileName }
    };
            
    // automatically cancels the request after some time only to reproduce 
    // the issue
    
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
    try
    {
        cts.CancelAfter(3000);
    
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await
            _httpClient.PostAsync("api/filetransfer", content, cts.Token);
    
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    
        return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<int(cancellationToken: 
            cts.Token);
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         throw;
     }
}
```

The problem is that, although the cancellation token is activated (`cts.IsCancellationRequested = true;`) in the client method, it does not activate in the controller's action, so the processing of the file continues even though the request has been canceled.
I have found out that the problem is the line `{ new StreamContent(fileStream), "file", fileName }`. By removing this line (so, not passing a file to stream), the cancellation token activation is correctly propagated to the controller's action.
By calling the endpoint with Postman, including a file, the cancellation token is correctly propagated to the endpoint. So it seems there is something wrong in my code, but everything seems correct to me.

Does anyone else have a problem with cancellation requests not reaching the endpoint while posting a file in a multipart/form-data in ASP.NET Core?

**EDIT:** After replacing the code inside the controller's action with a simple `while` loop which checks if the cancellation token is canceled, the issue occurs also when posting the multipart file with Postman. So, it seems that this problem is related to multipart content in general in ASP.NET Core 7. Probably a bug.

Comment: Does it work outside windows service? (E.g. when you call it from Postman or another API client IDE)

Comment: Have you looked into the source of `StreamContent`? It might have a way to pass a CT directly to it. Or you might need to write your own cancelable streaming content.

Comment: Why are you using `File.OpenRead`, which is explicitly not async-aware, then expecting asynchronous semantics? You need to explicitly create a `FileStream` using `FileOptions.Asynchronous`.

Comment: @IanKemp It does not work even with the use of an asynchronous `FileStream`.

Comment: @StephenCleary `StreamContent` does not have a constructor which accepts a cancellation token.

Comment: It seems that `HttpContext.RequestAborted` in the controller's action does not properly update when the http request is canceled by the client. Maybe a bug in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

My code was perfect and the problem was not due to any of the potential issues suggested by other people here or to a possible bug in ASP.NET Core.

It was a sneaky service installed on my development machine which interfered with http abort requests.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).